# Why am I getting extra line and/or paragraph spacing when printing, despite setting @media print styles?

Tags: css, printing, google-chrome-devtools

Using Chrome dev tools to preview my print styles everything looks good, but when I go to actually print the page, I have the following problems:

1. after a few, seemingly random paragraphs, there is a large extra space, as though the margin-bottom (or the margin-top of the next element) has been added to.
2. in some cases, a paragraph itself is broken (not at a page break), with extra vertical space added between two lines of the paragraph.
3. on most pages, the top of the first line of a page is cut off, appearing instead at the bottom of the previous page. This problem is improved (but not eliminated) by setting the line-height to "normal."

How do I trouble shoot these issues, since they don't show when rendering print styles in Chrome?

Answer (score -2):

`How do I trouble shoot these issues, since they don't show when rendering print styles in Chrome?`

Do a <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd> (to print) and then use the print preview as your guide. I did this on one of my sites and it worked well for me ~ no paper wasted.

Comment: That's what I've been doing, but that only shows me if it's working or not, but it doesn't show me the cause of the problems.