# How to resolve extra blank space when printing in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, printing

When printing from Chrome, my page has extra space between lines - in the middle of a <p>!

[Image of discrepancy between print emulation and print preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JAkaB.jpg)

The extra space is **consistently** at the same position on multiple pages, and approx. 80% of a line height.

I cannot debug it, since the CSS print emulation does not have this extra space. Also it prints fine in Firefox and Edge.

Seems similar to this question with no answer:
[Why am I getting extra line and/or paragraph spacing when printing, despite setting @media print styles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57081445/why-am-i-getting-extra-line-and-or-paragraph-spacing-when-printing-despite-sett)

Similar questions:

- [Remove blank page when printing on google chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38416591/remove-blank-page-when-printing-on-google-chrome)
- [Inexplicable empty space on print from Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35001518/inexplicable-empty-space-on-print-from-chrome)

Based on these, I have tried adding disabling transitions, forcing line-height and unsetting orphans and widows:

```
@media print {
  * {
        -webkit-transition:none!important;
        -moz-transition:none!important;
        -ms-transition:none!important;
        -o-transition:none!important;
        transition:none!important
  }
  
  h1, p {
      orphans: unset;
      widows: unset;
      line-height: 1.15 !important;
  }
}
```

Any tips on how to find the root cause?
[Image of the print emulation HTML etc.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OL4Gb.png)

[image: Here's a gif, showing many different fonts, line spacing, width, etc. All of them have this extra space at the same spot.]

Answer (score 0):

just change the value of your line-height to less than 1 or use `display:inline-block` for p

Comment: Thanks, but neither of these suggestions work.
A line-height of <1 is not legible, and still the problem persists.
With inline-block, the <p> doesn't start until after the 'blank space', so this causes even more blank space.
In both of these cases, the print emulation looks fine, but the print preview has these issues.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is caused by the text `div` being 'relative'ly positioned `position: relative;` on the page.

You can't change to positioning 'absolute' either, since this breaks printing in Firefox ([known bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=267029))

Positioning the two text divs using a grid instead works in all browsers.